# Can excitons always be formed from electrons and holes with the same wavevector?

Tags: optics, solid-state-physics

In order to be able to move together through the solid, the electron and hole making up an exciton must have the same **group velocity**. Given the dispersion $E(k)$ the group velocity is given by
$$v_g=\frac{1}{\hbar}\frac{dE}{dk}$$

I was told that it is possible for an exciton to be formed from a conduction electron and hole having the same $k$; that is, if
$k_e=k_h$. But this contradicts the condition mentioned above. Generally the group velocity of a conduction electron and hole are different for the same values of $k$, after all.

Of course, at the band extrema this can happen. In cases where the bands have the same shape, this can happen. But what about generally, when we are talking about wavevectors corresponding not to any extrema, and different looking valence and conduction bands?

I would love an explanation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of group velocity only makes sense when you form a wavepacket (a superposition of states with different wavevectors $k$). Typically this will be narrowly distributed around some central wavevector $k_0$ at which point we evaluate the group velocity, which then essentially tells us how fast the wavepacket moves.

However, for the exciton you mention, in which $k_e=k_h$, the electron and hole are in a state of well-defined wavevector, meaning the idea of group velocity is not applicable. Such states are not localized in space and it does not make sense to think of the particles as moving through the solid.

Note that, in general, the exciton does not need to have $k_h=k_e$. It has total wavevector $Q=k_e-k_h$ (assuming one dimension for simplicity) so $k_h=k_e$ is just the special case of $Q=0$. One can then form a wavepacket for the exciton itself by considering a superposition of different $Q$ centred around some $Q_0$.